# SQL : Compare table data and update the correct value in tables

Tags: sql, db2

I have the below data discrepancy in few of the tables which needs to be corrected using update queries in sql

the master table( take table A) table contains 2 primary key value for the same product like below,

```
------------------
PRRFNBR|PRNBR
-------|--------
XXXX   |123
YYYY   |123
----------------
```

And these reference keys used in 2 tables like below ,

Table B:

```
----------------------
SUPRFNBR |SUSPRNBR
---------------------
XXXX     |   234
-------------------
```

Table C:

```
-------------------
SEPRFNBR |  SESUPRNBR
-------------------
YYYY     | 435
--------------------
```

Now I need to compare all these 3 tables and update the SEPRFNBR in  TABLE C with the reference key available in table B (SUPRFNBR ) ( Like the reference key XXXX needs to be updated in table C if the same PRNBR is having 2 primary key values in TABLE A)

Comment: Could you explain a little more about the logic please. So far I think you want Table C updated to the majority of Table A and B - what do you mean with the last sentence? More details or examples would be helpful

Comment: Hi Michael, The logic works like this , When i insert a record in TABLE C it uses a different reference number from TABLE A instead of same reference number used in TABLE B ( like if xxxx is used in table b then the program uses YYYY from table C instead of XXXX. I am not able to change the insert function now since active orders are mapped to both the reference numbers. hence as a workaround i need to update the records in TABLE C with the same reference number is used in table B ( XXXX) if the given line is having more than 2 reference number in table A ) .

Comment: Do you mean that in table C you want to change YYYY to XXXX?

Comment: Yes dan , the value in TABLE C needs to change from YYYY to XXXX if the line having 2 entries in Table A

Comment: can i get the result using loop function in shell ?, any idea ?

Comment: Now i have modified the values in table B & table C to show the data available in my database . Table B & C contains only the reference numbers not the actual product numbers to perform a direct update by referencing table B & C. Could you please take a look into it and let me know how to update the reference key in TABLE C as like TABLE B ?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic - as far as understood - does not need a reference to table A as different SUPRFNBR & SEPRFNBR would qualify for the update

```
update c set SEPRFNBR = (select SUPRFNBR from b where b.SUPRNBR = c.SEPRNBR)
```

If for some (undescribed) reason the lookup to table A is necessary it could be extended so something like

```
update c set SEPRFNBR = (select SUPRFNBR from b 
                          where b.SUPRNBR = c.SEPRNBR) 
                            and (select count(*) from a 
                                  where b.SUPRNBR = a.PRNBR) > 1)"
```

You may vary the solution depending on other side constraints you may have. This is just ment as a solution idea.

Comment: Thanks michael for the SQL's . Now i have modified the values in table B & table C to show the data available in the database . Table B & C contains only the reference numbers not the actual product numbers to perform a direct update by referencing table B & C. Could you please take a look into it and let me know how to update the reference key in TABLE C as like TABLE B ?

Comment: So there is no way to check if there are two numbers (whcih belong together)  in table A and the logic you described is incomplete.

Comment: I have added more details in the below link , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43365754/compare-rows-using-a-cursor-in-db2-and-perform-update    could you please take a look into it and let me know how to get the expected results using cursors in db2 ?